# Angular Subscription to SQL DB

Tags: sql, angular, typescript

I am having difficulty grasping some of the concepts.  Such as I have created a subscription to my SQL DB (users) upon login and I am able to present the data on the page (DOM).  However, I a now trying to pull out specific data from the item to save for later use in my typescript file.

**login.component.ts**

```
this.usersService.getUsers()
         .subscribe((result: users) => (this.users[0] = result));
```

**users.service.ts**

```
public getUsers() : Observable<users> {
    let userEmail = sessionStorage.getItem('userEmail');
    return this.http.get<users>(`${environment.apiUrl}/${this.url}/${userEmail}`);
```

**login.component.html**

```
<div class="row" style="background-color:transparent;">
        <mat-card *ngFor="let user of user" class="ecard">
            <mat-card-title>{{user.role}}</mat-card-title>
        </mat-card>

    </div>
```

This works as expected.

However, I would like to use information from the 'user' to perform other functions in the ts file.

The below actions are returning undefined values

```
console.log(this.users);
console.log(this.users.values);
```

And this action returns an error of "can not read 'fname'

```
sessionStorage.setItem('userDisplayName', this.users[0].fname);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An observable is asynchronous. So you only can be sure you get the value **inside** "subscribe function" (well, in subscribe function you can call to another function passing as argument the response)

```
**WRONG**
this.usersService.getUsers()
         .subscribe((result: users) => (this.users[0] = result));

sessionStorage.setItem('userDisplayName', this.users[0].fname); //<--this is outside 
                                                                // subscribe function

**OK**
this.usersService.getUsers()
         .subscribe((result: users) => {
             this.users[0] = result;
             sessionStorage.setItem('userDisplayName', this.users[0].fname);
         })

**OR OK Too**
this.usersService.getUsers()
         .subscribe((result: users) => {
             this.users[0] = result;
             doSomething(this.users[0])
          })
doSomething(user:any)
{
    sessionStorage.setItem('userDisplayName', this.users[0].fname);
}
```

NOTE: To log or store the result, it's common use the rxjs operator "tap" in the observable. This operator makes that, when someone subscribe it's executed the function

```
public getUsers() : Observable<users> {
    let userEmail = sessionStorage.getItem('userEmail');
    return this.http.get<users>(`${environment.apiUrl}/${this.url}/${userEmail}`).pipe(
        tap((res:any)=>{
           sessionStorage.setItem('userDisplayName', res.fname);
        })
        )
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation and example. As a follow up to your solution, I noticed that I am not able to immediately access the values from 'this.user[0]' when using sessionStorage. However, if I refresh the page, the values are present. Any thoughts?